# How to get state from different slices in another slice thunk and do something with it?

Tags: reactjs, redux-thunk, redux-toolkit

I have three slices `ProductSlice`, `CategorySlice` and `BrandSlice`. Each slice has `createAsyncThunk` which makes fetch request for products, categories and brands.

`CategorySlice` (`BrandSlice` the same):

```
export const fetchCategories = createAsyncThunk('category/fetchCategories', async () => {
  const response = await fetch(`${BASE_URL}/categories.json`);
  const data = await response.json();
  const categories: Category[] = handleObj(data);
  return categories;
});

    builder.addCase(fetchCategories.fulfilled, (state, { payload }) => {
      state.categories = payload;
      state.isLoading = false;
    });
```

App component dispatches three fetch requests.

```
  useEffect(() => {
     dispatch(fetchCategories());
     dispatch(fetchProducts());
     dispatch(fetchBrands()); 
  }, [dispatch]);
```

I need to get data from brands and categories. Then get data for products and add some data to each product and only after that set it to `ProducSlice` state. The data should come from categories and brands. I'm trying to it in `ProductSlice` `createAsyncThunk` this way:

```
export const fetchProducts = createAsyncThunk<Product[], void, { state: RootState }>(
  'product/fetchProducts',
  async (_, { getState }) => {
    const response = await fetch(`${BASE_URL}/products.json`);
    const data = await response.json();
    const products: Product[] = handleObj(data);

    const { brands } = await getState().brand;
    const { categories } = await getState().category;

    const productsWithUpdatedBrandsAndCategories = products.map((product) => {
      const category = categories.find((category) => category.id === product.category.id);
      const brand = brands.find((brand) => brand.id === product.brand.id);

      if (!category && !brand) return product;

      return {
        ...product,
        category: {
          ...category,
          name: category && category.name,
        },
        brand: {
          ...brand,
          name: brand && brand.name,
        },
      };
    }) as Product[];

    return productsWithUpdatedBrandsAndCategories;
  }
);
```

The problem is that from time to time the brands or categories in ProductSlice in thunk are empty arrays (I mean the thunk fires when the data has not came from other slices..so `productsWithUpdatedBrandsAndCategories` do nothing then). How to deal with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems there is a dependency on `fetchCategories` and `fetchBrands` and subsequent state updates prior to being able to dispatch `fetchProducts` to have the brand and categories state available.

I suggest a little refactor to dispatch the first two actions and wait for them to resolve then dispatching the third.

Example:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const fetchData = async () => {
    try {
      // fetch brands and categories and wait for actions to resolve
      await Promise.all([
        dispatch(fetchBrands()),
        dispatch(fetchCategories()),
      ]);

      // now fetch products
      dispatch(fetchProducts());
    } catch(error) {
      // handle or ignore errors?
    }
  };
  
  fetchData();
}, [dispatch]);
```

...

```
export const fetchProducts = createAsyncThunk<Product[], void, { state: RootState }>(
  'product/fetchProducts',
  async (_, { getState }) => {
    const response = await fetch(`${BASE_URL}/products.json`);
    const data = await response.json();
    const products: Product[] = handleObj(data);

    const {
      brand: { brands },
      category: { categories },
    } = getState();

    const productsWithUpdatedBrandsAndCategories = products.map((product) => {
      const category = categories.find((category) => category.id === product.category.id);
      const brand = brands.find((brand) => brand.id === product.brand.id);

      if (!category && !brand) return product;

      return {
        ...product,
        category: {
          ...category,
          name: category && category.name,
        },
        brand: {
          ...brand,
          name: brand && brand.name,
        },
      };
    }) as Product[];

    return productsWithUpdatedBrandsAndCategories;
  }
);
```

Comment: Thank you. It works. If you don't mind I'll ask one more question. I render these products like a todo list with a button Add Product. This button is active only if there's at least one category and one brand otherwise button is disabled and placeholders shown based on isLoading state, brands.length > 0, category.length > 0. isLoading state comes from ProductSlice on pending = true, on fullfiled = false. Now I see in console 4 isLoading=false -> 1 isLoading = true -> 1 isLoading = false...and placeholders don't work (they blink all together). How to fix that?

Comment: @qweezz Is there more than one `isLoading` state? Maybe one in each slice? Do you need to create a derived/computed state that if *any* of the asynchronous actions are pending, i.e. "isLoading", that the button should be disabled, and only when all pending actions have succeeded the button is enabled? If this issue requires a more serious look then it would be better to post a new question with the relevant details and slice code examples. If you do create a new post then feel free to ping me here in a comment with a link to the post and I can take a look when available.

Comment: Yes. You correct. Each slice has a isLoading state which trigeers on loading/update...pending = true, fulfilled = false. I'm not very smart, sorry. May I ask you to give a more detailed comment what should I do to fix that. Unfortunatelly this is not clear for me: "need to create a derived/computed state that if any of the asynchronous actions are pending"

Comment: Is that correct? Create a new slice say IsLoading. Add two reducers in it, one makes isLoading true and second one makes IsLoading false. Then in every component where I dispatch actions for fetching/updating Products, Brands, Categories ...dispatch these two actions?

Comment: @qweezz No, I meant something more like using `useSelector` to select out the state of each slice, e.g. `const { brands, categories, products } = useSelector(state => state);` and then compute `const isLoading = [brands.isLoading, categories.isLoading, products.isLoading].some(Boolean);`. Like I said though, if you need more specific help for this part, asking a new question with all the relevant details might be more beneficial to both you and future readers since it's a bit off-topic for this post.